# How to fix the error mismatched input 'partition' for window functions in spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I'd like to run a window function in Spark SQL. I have Zeppelin sitting on top of a Spark cluster with Hadoop.

I'd like to add a row number to a table and group it by a combination of two IDs.

This is my data.

```
food      aisle      item    date_added
pear      1          1234    '2020-01-01 10:12'
banana    2.         1233    '2020-01-02 10:12'
banana    2          1211    '2020-01-03 10:12'
banana    2          1412    '2020-01-04 10:12'
apple     1          1452    '2020-01-05 10:12'
apple     1          1334    '2020-01-06 10:12'
```

I'd like to turn the data into this

```
food      aisle      item    date_added             rn
pear      1          1234    '2020-01-01 10:12'     1
banana    2          1233    '2020-01-02 10:12'     3
banana    2          1211    '2020-01-03 10:12'     2
banana    2          1412    '2020-01-04 10:12'     1
apple     1          1452    '2020-01-05 10:12'     2
apple     1          1334    '2020-01-06 10:12'     1
```

This is my query

```
%sql

select
    food,
    aisle,
    item,
    row_number() over (order by date_added desc 
                            partition by food, aisle 
                            rows between unbounded preceeding and current row) as rn
from fruits
```

This is the error

```
mismatched input 'partition' expecting {')', ',', 'RANGE', 'ROWS'}(line 5, pos 28)
```

How do I solve this error with Spark SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
row_number() over (partition by food, aisle order by date_added desc) as rn
```

A window frame specification is not needed for the ranking functions (`row_number()`, `rank()`, and `dense_rank()`).